# pyspark : Operate on column sets in parallel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

If I was interested in working on groups of rows in Spark, I could, for example add a column that denoted group membership and use a pandas groupby to operate on these rows in parallel (independently). Is there a way to do this for columns instead? I have a df with many feature columns and 1 target column and I would like to run calculations on each set{column_i, target} for i=1...p.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. The mindset has to be on the row level parallelism because Spark is partitioned by row and not by column. So in a partition you will find  a record with all of it's columns, but a column won't know all of the other values in it's column because they are spread across workers. Your best get is using mapPartitions to parallelize on the row level and then run your column operations sequentially.

Comment: Could you transpose the DF (and repeat the target as many times as there are columns) and then add a group column (to each target and column that are now rows) and use pandas group by functions?

Comment: Big if on if you can transpose. I feel it's too expensive sometimes. Yes it might work, but it's a bit hard to advice without more info on the use case. You might be forcing a bad fit. 

The answer for you if you want to use Pandas functions it to use Spark [MapInPandas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.mapInPandas) where each partition is a DataFrame or you can use [Fugue](https://fugue-tutorials.readthedocs.io/) to apply Pandas code per partition.

Comment: If you can construct a minimum example with inputs and outputs, I can make a code example for you.